# Initialize a JavaScript object using JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to do the following

```
var my_json = {
    a : 'lemon',
    b : 1
}

function obj(json){
    this.a = 'apple';
    this.b = 0;
    this.c = 'other default';
}
```

after assigning

```
var instance = obj(my_json)
```

I want to get

```
instance.a == 'lemon'
```

Comment: By the Title of the question, maybe a question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript  will be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(var key in json) {
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this[key] = json[key];
    }
}
```

The `if` block is optional if you know for sure that nothing is every going to extend `Object.prototype` (which is a bad thing anyway).

Comment: could you please explain your last sentence better?

Comment: If you extend `Object.prototype`, iterating over objects will include the properties you added to the prototype which is most likely not what you want when iterating over an object coming from JSON. If a property comes from the prototype, the `hasOwnProperty` check will fail so it will prevent breakage as only the properties which are actually in the passed objects will be copied to your object.

Answer (score 2):

If you want defaults how about;

```
function obj(json){
  var defaults = {
    a: 'apple',
    b: 0,
    c: 'other default'
  }

  for (var k in json)
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(k))
      defaults[k] = json[k];

  return defaults
}
```