# How do I cast a list of JSON objects into a list of TypeScript objects without losing properties on the TypeScript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this Customer class:

```
export class Customer {
    id: number;
    company: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    name(): string {
        if (this.company)
            return this.company;
        if (this.lastName && this.firstName)
            return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName;
        if (this.lastName)
            return this.lastName;
        if (this.firstName)
            return this.firstName;
        if (this.id > 0)
            return "#" + this.id;
        return "New Customer";
    }
}
```

In my controller I pull down a list of customers:

```
export class CustomersController {
    static $inject = ["customerService", "workflowService"];

    ready: boolean;
    customers: Array<Customer>;

    constructor(customerService: CustomerService, workflowService: WorkflowService) {
        customerService.getAll().then(
            (response) => {
                this.customers = response.data;
                this.ready = true;
            },
            () => {
                this.ready = true;
            }
        );
        workflowService.uiCustomer.reset();
    }
}
angular.module("app")
    .controller("CustomersController", ["customerService", "workflowService", CustomersController]);
```

If it helps, getAll() looks like this:

```
    getAll(): ng.IHttpPromise<Array<Customer>> {
        return this.http.get("/api/customers");
    }
```

It's this statement that's causing me grief: `this.customers = response.data;`

But response.data is strongly typed, so shouldn't it "know" about Customer and name()?

When I do that, of course I am overwriting my strongly typed array with the dumb JSON one, which doesn't have my name() method on it.

So how do I keep my name method without copying every property of every object in the list?

Is this bad design on my part? Having these read-only properties was really common in C#, but I'm a little new to the javascript world. Should I be using a utility class instead?

My current work-around:

```
this.customers = response.data.map(customer => {
    return angular.copy(customer, new Customer());
});
```

Feels wrong to build a whole new array and copy all those fields (in my real project Customer has many more properties).

Edit: I've found a few related SO questions, such as [Mapping JSON Objects to Javascript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783327/mapping-json-objects-to-javascript-objects) as mentioned by @xmojmr. My question was specific to TypeScript and I was wondering if TypeScript had any facilities of its own that would generate the javascript to make this a non-issue. If that's not the case, and we're sure TypeScript doesn't aim to solve this class of problem, then we can regard this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping JSON Objects to Javascript Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783327/mapping-json-objects-to-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're exactly right about what is happening. Typing in typescript mainly provides you with compiler checking. Under the covers, everything compiles to JavaScript which isn't strongly typed.

So, when you say:

```
getAll(): ng.IHttpPromise<Array<Customer>> {
    return this.http.get("/api/customers");
}
```

all you are really doing is telling is telling the compiler "Hey, I'm pretty sure my api endpoint is going to return an array of `Customer` objects." But as you know, it really just returns a "dumb JSON" array.

What you could consider doing, is creating an interface that describes the JSON object being returned by the API endpoint. Something like:

```
interface ICustomer {
    id: number;
    company: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

And then `getAll()` becomes:

```
getAll(): ng.IHttpPromise<Array<ICustomer>> {
    return this.http.get("/api/customers");
}
```

Then you could have a class who's constructor takes `ICustomer` as a parameter. Or you could create a class with a static method that takes `ICustomer` and returns the "name".

Obviously, what you are doing now works, but I think you're right to be looking for something that better communicates the intent.

Comment: Does TypeScript have a feature for this? For example, maybe I *don't* tell TypeScript that my API returns a Customer, and instead tell it to cast the results into a Customer List, could it then solve this problem for me? If that's not the kind of thing TypeScript can/should do, then I'm satisfied with your answer, or just calling my question a duplicate.

Comment: Unfortunately, TypeScript does not allow you to use type casting to actually change the structure of an object. It is all about using types to provide compiler checking for errors.

Comment: On the other hand,  using types can really improve the readability, and maintainability of the code. By choosing good class names, you can make  an otherwise complex object transformation clear.