# How to declare functions so they are available when assigning objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object in javascript:

```
export class A{

    name:string;

    sayHi() {
      console.log("Hi " + name);
    }

}
```

I'm filling an array of type A using a backend service, but when I'm going to use sayHi I'm getting that the funcion is not defined:

```
backService.get().subscribe( (a:A) => a.sayHi());
```

Now my guess is that since the back end service response is just a Json it does not have a way to actually add the function reference to this object.

How can I define the "sayHi" function inside the A class so it is always available?
I could create another class or a static method but I would like to have this logic encapsulated inside the class reference.

Thanks.

Comment: as you are using class. you need to create an instance of it.

Comment: Well this all depends on what `backService.get()` does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315147/json-to-javascript-class

Comment: @Liam it invokes a backend servie using HTTPClientService

Comment: @Sodhisaab I am not creating an instance of it because it is being assigned from a backend service

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using RxJs Observables for the `backService`. If So, you can easily map your json objects to `A` objects like so:

```js
// dont forget to
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";

export class A{
    name:string;
    constructor(obj: A){ // add constructor (or factory)
       this.name = obj.name;
    }
    sayHi() {
      console.log("Hi " + name);
    }
}

backend
 .get()
 .pipe(
    // map normal objects to instances of A
    map( arr => arr.map( item=>new A(item as any) ) 
 )
 .subscribe( objects => {
    // do whatever
 })
```

Comment: the constructor should probably take in an `any` if he's getting JSON back from the service, not an `A`

Comment: @MattM yes indeed, I just find it to help the IDE if I declare it this way. Also, I'm not a big fan of the 'any' type.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it, you need to do something like

```
let test:A = new A();
test.name = 'Bob';
test.sayHi();
```

IDK what's going on with your backservice, but it looks like you're assuming `get` will hydrate an instance of `A`.  If you're just returning the JSON from the backService, then no, it will not have that function.  You need code somewhere that's taking the JSON and hydrating an instance of `A`.

Comment: Ok. Then I need to create an instance and then assign fill the properties from the backend service, right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. There are libraries that will do this for you called ORMs (object relational mappings).  Here is a reddit link on a discussion about ones people use: https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/98rhh5/what_is_the_recommended_library_for_handling_json/