# Return of toString() loses type after traversing the wire on HttpClient in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I made a Foobar class with a toString() and it works well except when the Foobar is returned from a rest call.  Below is the code and output.  FOOBAR-1 works as expected, but FOOBAR-2 does not return a string, but an Object. Why?  FOOBAR-3 returns as expected so it knows it's a Foobar.

app.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Foobar } from './foobar';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    console.log("FOOBAR-1 IS " + new Foobar().toString());
    const remoteUrl:string = 'http://localhost:8080/foobar';
    let observable:Observable<Foobar> =  this.http.get<Foobar>(encodeURI(remoteUrl));  
    observable.subscribe(
      (foobar: Foobar) => {
        console.log("FOOBAR-2 IS "+foobar.toString());
        console.log("FOOBAR-3 IS "+foobar.foo);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

foobar.ts

```
export class Foobar {

    foo:string ='bar';

    toString(): string {
        return this.foo;
    };
}
```

Console output:

```
app.component.ts:18 FOOBAR-1 IS bar
app.component.ts:23 FOOBAR-2 IS [object Object]
app.component.ts:24 FOOBAR-3 IS bar
```

Is it possible to use a toString() on any object returned from HttpClient?  What is happening here?

Comment: You could serialize an object using `JSON.stringify(obj)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP call can only return strings, in your case likely the JSON string `'{"foo": "bar"}'`. That is unserialised into the Javascript object `{ foo: 'bar' }`. That object behaves exactly as you're demonstrating:

```js
const foobar = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log("FOOBAR-2 IS " + foobar.toString());
console.log("FOOBAR-3 IS " + foobar.foo);
```

It's not an instance of `class Foobar`, since you've never instantiated it as such. The HTTP client wouldn't know to do that. The type annotations just suggest that the returned object will behave like `Foobar`, they don't actually cast the type.

Comment: This is a paradigm shift from Java.  I understand that I have the JSON representation, but then I need to instantiate a Foobar?  What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: The only real way is to have your `Foobar` accept a plain object as a parameter and take its values from there, or have a factory function/method for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33778934/476 for inspiration. There are probably ways to muck around with the prototype chain and whatnot to basically cast the existing object and make it behave like an instance; but that's error prone once your classes actually *do* things in the constructor and try to keep a specific state and such.