# Add method to JSON parsed object

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have an object that is stored locally on my users PC, stringified with JSON. I noticed that when i parse it back the methods disappear. What is the most efficient way to augment an object with a method?

EDIT:
Example:

```
var data = {
    user: {
        username: "Adam"
    }
    //function goes here
}

var myFunction = function(){/* code here*/}
```

Comment: Mind sharing the object with an example function on it?

Comment: This may help: [Casting plain objects to function instances (“classes”) in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11810028/218196)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "efficient" or did you just add that word for no reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your problem, you can do like below.

```
var data = {
    user: {
        username: "Adam"
    },
    functionName : "myFunction"
}

var myFunction = function(){ alert("a"); }

var stringyJson = JSON.stringify(data);

var parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringyJson);

window[parsedJson.functionName]();
```

And if you want to pass arguments to function then add those in json and use like `window[parsedJson.functionName](arg1, arg2);`

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign the function to a property of the object:

```
var data = {
    user: {
        username: "Adam"
    }
    //function goes here
}

var myFunction = function(){/* code here*/}

data.myFunction = myFunction;
```