# JavaScript Exception: is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I've created two object prototypes in JavaScript. These are the object constructor functions. You can see that the `Board` object contains an array of `PostIt` objects:

```
function PostIt(id, msg, img, pos) {
  this.id = id;
  this.msg = msg;
  this.img = img;
  this.pos = pos.slice(); // copy of array
}

function Board() {
  this.postIts = [];   // Empty array of PostIt objects
}
```

Every prototype has its methods (getters/setters) and also `Board` has methods to push and pop PostIt objects from the array.

I've also implemented a mechanism  in `Board` to save & retrieve the array by means of localStorage:

```
Board.prototype.save = function () {
  // Clean localstorage first
  localStorage.clear();

  if (this.getNumPostIts() > 0) { // It array is not empty
    localStorage.setItem('myboard', JSON.stringify(this.postIts));
  }
};

// Retrieve array of postit objects from local storage
Board.prototype.load = function () {
  this.postIts = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('myboard')));
};
```

The PostIt objects are retrieved correctly, but I'm not sure about what happens when I assign them to the `this.postIts` array of the Board object:

```
this.postIts = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('myboard')));
```

Once I've done this on loading the site, when I try to call a method for any of the postit objects in the array, I get an exception. For example, the following code after loading the document

```
myBoard = new Board();

if (localStorage.myboard) { // Local Storage has data
  // Retrieve data from local storate and dump it to myBoard
  myBoard.load();

  // Display Id for every postit
  for (var i=0; i < myBoard.getNumPostIts(); i++) {
    var pId = myBoard.getPostItByArrayIndex(i).getId();
    console.log("PostIt #%d has id = %d", i, pId);
  }    
}
```

Calling the getId() method of the PostIt object raises an exception:
jQuery.Deferred exception: myBoard.getPostItByArrayIndex(...).getId is not a function TypeError: myBoard.getPostItByArrayIndex(...).getId is not a function

I don't understand why "getId" is not a function. Is there something wrong when I call this getter method?
EDIT:
.getId() is a getter method of the `PostIt` object prototype:

```
PostIt.prototype.getId = function() {
  return this.id;
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing (because you haven't shown it) that `getId` is a function on `PostIt.prototype`?

Comment: yes, just added the getter code to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON format does not store the prototypes of the objects you convert to JSON. So when you parse those JSON strings again, the objects will just be plain objects, not related in any way to the prototype, like `PostIt`. By consequence prototype methods like `getId` are not available to those objects any more.

Similarly you would also lose the the direct methods on objects, as JSON does not provision for the function format.

#### How to make it work

I would first change the `PostIt` constructor, so that it has defaults for all arguments. More specifically, it needs some adjustment for the `pos` property:

```
function PostIt(id, msg, img, pos) {
  this.id = id;
  this.msg = msg;
  this.img = img;
  this.pos = Array.isArray(pos) ? pos.slice() : []; // default is empty array
}
```

And now you can use `Object.assign` to convert the JSON parsed objects back to `PostIt` objects:

```
Board.prototype.load = function () {
  this.postIts = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('myboard')))
                     .map(x => Object.assign(new PostIt, x));
};
```

Comment: Thx, I didn't know. Is there any other way to store/retrieve from local storage and being able to call the prototype methods?

Comment: @rodrunner: this has been asked before a couple of times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810028/casting-plain-objects-to-function-instances-classes-in-javascript for example.

Comment: I added code that will do it, specific for this case.

Comment: awesome compact coding