# How to return the object of specified type from JSON representation

Tags: javascript, json, prototype

The function must return a new object of the specified type (prototype of the specified object is passed as an argument) from JSON representation (also passed as an argument).

No, any tries were successful. And I am expecting an explanation rather than just a solution. Thanks.

```
/**
 * Returns the object of specified type from JSON representation
 *
 * @param {Object} proto
 * @param {string} json
 * @return {object}
 *
 * @example
 * var r = fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype, '{"width":10, "height":20}');
 */
```

```
function fromJSON(proto, json) {
    // ???
}
```

Passed arguments:

```
proto: MockType.prototype,
json: '{ "a":10, "b":20, "c":30 }'
```

Expected result:

```
new MockType(10,20,30)
```

Comment: There are no objects in a JSON string; it's just text.

Comment: Show us what you tried.  Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, but we're happy to help you get your solution working.

Comment: `fromJSON = Object.setPrototypeOf` would do, but have a look at [Casting plain objects to function instances (“classes”) in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11810028/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you want to achieve:

```js
function fromJSON(proto, json) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(json);
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    
    return new proto.constructor(...values);
}

function Rectangle(w, h) {
  this.width = w;
  this.height = h;
}

const obj = fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype, '{"width": 10, "height": 20}');

console.log(obj);
```

Given a `constructor function prototype` create an object using as params the values in the `json`.

In the prototype you can find the `constructor` so, you can use it to create your object as in the example.

Comment: Don't do that, JSON keys are unordered and you are relying on `Object.values` to get them in the order required by the constructor. `fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype, '{"height": 20, "width": 10}');` would likely fail.

Comment: I know, it is just to know what he is referring to, and if he wants a solution based on that he must have an agreement with its JSON and its constructors.