# What does it mean ' return new proto.constructor(...values);'?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I find solution to my task here:
[How to return the object of specified type from JSON representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278307/how-to-return-the-object-of-specified-type-from-json-representation)
However, I cannot find meaning of this `return new proto.constructor(...values);` nor can I understand.

task:

```js
/**
 * Returns the object of specified type from JSON representation
 *
 * @param {Object} proto
 * @param {string} json
 * @return {object}
 *
 * @example
 * var r = fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype, '{"width":10, "height":20}');
 */
function fromJSON(proto, json) {
    // ???
}


const obj = fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype, '{"width": 10, "height": 20}');

console.log(obj);
```

and the answer is:

```js
function fromJSON(proto, json) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(json);
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    
    return new proto.constructor(...values);
}

function Rectangle(w, h) {
  this.width = w;
  this.height = h;
}
```

Comment: You create new instance of passed in object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes