# Preserve instance type when saving to localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have a hard time figuring out how I should save my Class to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) such as when I retrieve it back, I can still call the instance methods I defined.

Here's an example that throws an error:

```
class Employee {
    constructor(name, gender, department, yy, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.skills = [];
    }

    addNewSkill(skill){
        this.skills.push(skill);
    }
}

const employee = new Employee({
    name: "John Doe", 
    gender: "male", 
    department: "CS", 
    email: "john@doe.com"
});

employee.addNewSkill("coding");

localStorage.setItem("employees", employee);

const retrievedEmployee = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("employee"));

// Throws Uncaught TypeError: retrievedEmployees[0].addNewSkill is not a 
// function.
retrievedEmployee.addNewSkill("reading");
```

Comment: Your syntax is fine; You just call `employee.addNewSkill('coding')` after you instantiate a new `Employee` and it pushes (adds) the passed `skill` argument in the `employee.skills` array. What's the problem?

Comment: Please add information about what your code is currently doing when you try executing it, what error it gives you, so we can help you better

Comment: when I instantiate a new employee I can push into the skills array, but in the existing employees I can't. Im testeting in the console.

Comment: An "existing" employee in your context is an employee you fetched from `localStorage`?

Comment: Indeed yes @NikKyriakides

Comment: Not sure if I miss understand the concept.. Right now the data from LocalStorage builds a dynamic table via a function. The whole concept is for me to add skills to the objects and updating them for the table

Comment: Probably dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810028/casting-plain-objects-to-function-instances-classes-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting plain objects to function instances ("classes") in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810028/casting-plain-objects-to-function-instances-classes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects **lose their type** when you turn them into strings using `JSON.stringify`. While their properties and values are preserved, any information about the fact that it's an `Employee` instance is lost.

After retrieval from `window.localStorage`, when you `JSON.parse` the saved string, you are creating plain objects instead of actual `Employee` objects therefore the retrieved objects lack the `employee.addNewSkill()` method.

You should ensure that your `Employee` class allows easy instantiation using `Employee`-like objects, then each time you retrieve a saved Employee from LocalStorage you instantiate a *new* `Employee` instance out of that object, like so:

Here's an example:

```
// The Employee now takes an Employee or Employee-like object 
// instead of separate arguments.
class Employee {
    constructor({ name, gender, department, yy, email, skills }) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.skills = skills || [];
    }

    addNewSkill(skill){
        this.skills.push(skill);
    }
}

// Create an Employee.
const employee = new Employee({
    name: "John Doe", 
    gender: "male", 
    department: "CS", 
    email: "john@doe.com"
});

// Add a skill.
employee.addNewSkill("coding");

// Turn employee to string and save to localStorage.
localStorage.setItem("employee", JSON.stringify(employee));

// Parse the string back into an Employee-like object and 
// use that object to construct a new Employee.
const retrievedEmployee = new Employee(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("employee")))

// Add another skill, using the Employee instance method.
retrievedEmployee.addNewSkill("reading");

// Logs Employee having 2 skills, one added *before* we saved to localStorage 
// and another skill we added *after* we retrieved him from localStorage.
console.log(retrievedEmployee);
```

For the record, I've had this problem before in a largeish project and used an npm module called [typeson](https://github.com/dfahlander/typeson) which allowed serialising and deserialising custom types.

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen Make it simpler for people that stumble upon this and have same issue; I can rollback if you want to.

Comment: No its okay, just had to figure out why. Im very thankful for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way, as Nik Kyriakides said in their comment. It would be used as such:

```
const Employee = require('./path/to/Employee.js');

const employee = new Employee('Jane Doe', 'Female', 'Development', 'jdoe@acme.com', [ 'html', 'css' ]);
employee.addNewSkill('javascript');
console.log(employee.skills);
```

Alternatively, you could use a setter:

```
...
set skills (skill) {
    this.skills.push(skill);
}
...
```

And then use it as:

```
const Employee = require('./path/to/Employee.js');

const employee = new Employee('Jane Doe', 'Female', 'Development', 'jdoe@acme.com', [ 'html', 'css' ]);
employee.skills = 'javascript';
console.log(employee.skills);
```

But syntactically, this reads as though it should be *setting* the array, not appending to it, so it's probably not a good choice for this context. I did want to mention it here though to give you some ideas of how you could get and set other class variables.

---

In your example, I would set this up in the following way:

Employee.js

```
module.exports = class Employee {
    constructor(name, gender, department, yy, email, skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.skills = [];
    }

    addNewSkill(skill){
        this.skills.push(skill);
    }
}
```

And then to work with your employee list, I would do something like this, which may need some tweaking, but just to give you an idea:

index.js

```
const Employee = require('./path/to/Employee.js');

const fs = require('fs');
const employees = fs.readFileSync('employees.txt').toString().split("\n");
let employeeList = [];
employees.forEach(employeeData => {
    const employee = JSON.parse(employeeData);
    const { name, gender, department, email, skills } = employee;
    employeeList.push(new Employee(name, gender, department, email, skills));
})

//do stuff with employeeList
```

Comment: I think the problem is the serialisation/deserialisation. Deserialised employees are plain Objects instead of actual `Employee`s, so they lack the `addNewSkill` method.

Comment: Yeh, you might be right. When parsing the objects they lose their methods as I understand. Hmmm

Comment: @NikKyriakides See how in my usage example, I require the class, create a new instance of the class, and then modify the instance? You could do the same with your employees which you have cached in local storage, that should work.

Just make sure that your class file exports the class. Otherwise the require() won't work.

Comment: You don't need to store the addSkill method to the local cache of employees; just store the values that you need to create the Employee instances.

Comment: I don't think the OP uses `require`, nor Node for that matter. The OP seems to be working with browser code.