# How to handle objects of a certain class in express sessions?

Tags: node.js, express, serialization, ecmascript-6, express-session

I am new to nodejs/express and currently trying to figure out how to store objects of a certain class in session storage (which I understand is basically a serialized version of the `req.session` object).

My (shortened example is this):

```
//cart.js
const CartItem = require('./cartItem');

class Cart {

    _items = [];

    constructor() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    addItem(item) {
        // ...
    }
}

module.exports = Cart;
```

```
//routes.js    
router.get('/create', function (req, res, next) {
    req.session.cart = new Cart();
    req.session.cart.addItem(new CartItem('Red Sox', 15, Math.round(Math.random() * 5)));

    console.log(req.session);

    res.render('cart/create.twig', {
        cart: req.session.cart
    });
});

router.get('/overview', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session);

    res.render('cart/overview.twig', {
        cart: req.session.cart
    });
});
```

The problem I am facing is that during the first action (`router.get('/create'`) the `req.session.cart` property holds an object of the `Cart` class.

However, when loading from the session in the second action (`router.get('/overview'`) the `req.session.cart` property holds an object of no special class.

I assume/understand that JavaScript cannot know during deserialization what kind of object this JSON once has been. But how do other people solve this issue ?

I have been checking out other session middlewares (I currently use express-session), but none of them mention in detail, whether they are able to do what I am looking for.

Please help me understand and resolve this issue :)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I would usually add a new method called `toJSON()` that would return a JSON-friendly object/string you can then use later on.

Comment: …and then also explicitly [create another instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11810861/1048572) using a `Cart.fromJSON()` method

Comment: I think @Bergi 's comment kind of is the right answer here. It's the most "vanilla" way of doing things in plain Node/Javascript without additional dependencies - so that's what I will be trying. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> I assume/understand that JavaScript cannot know during deserialization what kind of object this JSON once has been.

You are right, the property value in `req.session` would be serialized as JSON by store (check [express-session document](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)), and the default serialization/deserialization of JavaScript (`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`) does not recognize Class/Type information, that is the root cause of this problem.  It is a general issue on JavaScript serialization.

To solve this general issue and retain Class/Type information during JavaScript serialization/deserialization, I've made an npm module named [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer). It is pretty easy to sovle this Cart/CartItem problem with esserializer:

For `GET /create` interface, you can serialize `req.session.cart` with esserializer:

```
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
const Cart = require('./Cart');
const CartItem = require('./CartItem');

router.get('/create', function (req, res, next) {
    req.session.cart = new Cart();
    req.session.cart.addItem(new CartItem('Red Sox', 15, Math.round(Math.random() * 5)));

    res.render('cart/create.twig', {
        cart: ESSerializer.serialize(req.session.cart)
    });
});
```

Once we want to reconstruct this `Cart` object, with `CartItem` inside, just invoke the deserialize method of esserializer, and pass all related Classes as parameter:

```
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
const Cart = require('./Cart');
const CartItem = require('./CartItem');

router.get('/overview', function (req, res, next) {
    const cartInstance = ESSerializer.deserialize(serializedString, [Cart, CartItem]);
    console.log(cartInstance);
    //...
});
```

This reconstructed `cartInstance` object has all Class/Type information retained, including instance methods, if any.