Convert json to typescript object
I am trying to convert a json to object and access the attribute values in typescript. I have tried chatgpt but the answer from that is static considering there are only 2 games i.e game1 and game2. How can I convert it into class object considering there can be multiple games.
{
"defaultConfiguration": {
    "listedGames": {
        "game1": {
            "Id": 1,
            "contentPartnerSplit": {
                "partner1": 50,
                "partner2": 50
            },
            "regionalSplit": {
                "region1": 50,
                "region2": 20,
                "region3": 30
            }
        },
        "game2": {
            "Id": 2,
            "contentPartnerSplit": {
                "partner1": 30,
                "partner2": 70
            },
            "regionalSplit": {
                "region1": 50,
                "region2": 50
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

}
Below is what I tried
export class GamesConfig {
    defaultConfiguration?: {
        listedGames?: {
        games?: Map<string, Games>;
      }
    };
  }

export class Games {
    Id: string;
    regionalSplit: RegionalSplit;
    contentPartnerSplit: ContentPartnerSplit;
  }

But when I try to parse json and access attribute Id I get undefined
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(config)
jsonObj.defaultConfiguration?.listedGames?.games?.get('game1')?.Id


You sound like you don't know typescript, and want someone who does to just make a type for you. But we are here to help you learn, not do it for you. So what's stopping you from writing the types yourself? Have you read the docs on object types and index signatures? When you write a type that is informed by those links, what goes wrong? What is that type and what problems or error messages do you get?

This question is similar to: How do I cast a JSON Object to a TypeScript class?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Sorry my bad. Yes I am new to typescript and did try to parse it but not able to. I have pasted the code snippet I tried.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11810861/1048572. It sounds like you expect JSON.parse to magically instantiate your classes

There are some issue with the typing though. First, parsing won't return you Maps but Records. There's no such thing as .get() on Records, thus you must access it via ['game1']. Second, you're accessing listedGames?.games?, which does not exist in the provided json, that's why you receive undefined eventually. Instead, the games are directly within the listedGames property (listedGames?: Record<string, Game>;). To properly access the Id attribute of "game1", you'd use jsonObj.defaultConfiguration?.listedGames?.['game1']?.Id.

Thanks. It worked. I wasn't aware of Records.

A good read https://refine.dev/blog/typescript-record-type/#union-of-key-types
