# How to use JSON to stringify/parse a user-defined class

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse JSON String into a Particular Object Prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript)

So I have a class defined like

```
function ThisClass (a,b,c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
ThisClass.prototype.a_method = function(param) {
    //stuff
}


var instance = new MyClass(a,b,c);
var stringified = JSON.stringify(instance);
var parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);
```

When I stringify this and store it in a database it's all cool.  However, when I parse it after retrieval, it loses its class type,  so when viewing it after parsing in chrome's inspect tool, the object is shown as just a regular object, like `instance: Object` instead of `instance: MyClass`.

Because of this, the newly parsed variable `parsed` does not have any of the prototype methods associated with it at instantiation.  Any know how to do this, or if I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: yeah i think you're right, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can not, JSON is only meant to be used to serialize non circular data object variable.

This the [spec](http://www.json.org/) for more détails.

Comment: There is no reason to suspect there is a circular reference issue. (There are other things that are true in this context, that not being a good one.)

Comment: I've never said they where, I just tried to make a useful statement. The second thing to know after you cant serialize functions is about the circular references. I was just trying to be helpful. Thanks for the down vote. I hope it help you feeling better about yourself. Because it does make you look like a jerk.

Comment: What reason is there for *me* to down-vote this post? (I didn't. So, who "looks like the jerk" now? ;)