# How to store an object (of a class type) in browser's storage and retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I want to have a page-reload proof class instances in my Angular 2 application.

In my component's .ts file I have classes:

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  foo: Foo = new Foo();
  ngOnInit() {
    // This will always be 12, it would be nice if it would increase with each page refresh.
    this.foo.bar.baz += 1;
    console.log("baz: " + this.foo.bar.baz);
  }
}

class Bar {
  baz: number = 11;
}

class Foo {
  bar: Bar = new Bar()
}
```

I know that the `localStorage` ES6 thing can store strings. Do I have to write my own deserialization of complex class objects? 
Like (I think) suggested here: [Angular 2 map http response to instance of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573527/angular-2-map-http-response-to-instance-of-class#35573671)

Comment: what do you mean by *Do I have to write my own deserialization of complex class objects?*. Do you want to store `foo` in `localStorage`?

Comment: I want to have `foo` "rebuilt" after page reload. I mentioned deserialization since I can only store strings in `localService`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest with angular-2-local-storage node_module.

Steps:

1. Install `npm install angular-2-local-storage`
2. Make sure that the package is added in the config.js(systemjs or webpack)
3. Import the module and service as below

   ```
   import { LocalStorageModule,LocalStorageService} from 'angular-2-local-storage';
   ```
4. Add the module to imports array and service to providers array as

   ```
    imports: [ BrowserModule,
      LocalStorageModule.withConfig({storageType: 'localStorage'}), ],

    providers:[LocalStorageService],
   ```
5. Inject the Service as a dependency into component as below

   ```
   constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
           this.name = 'Angular-2-Local-Storage-Demo';
           this.localStorageService.add('a',this.user);
           console.log(this.localStorageService.get('a')); 
           this.valuFromLocalStorage= this.localStorageService.get('a')
   }
   ```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BOIyDOKgWey6UbNZrnAl?p=preview)**

Comment: Just a question.. is there any reason to suggest this lib instead of the [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: This library is for angular2 applications.

Comment: I m sorry I didnt get you

Comment: I'm just asking why you're suggesting to use that library instead of the "original" `localStorage`.. How is It diferent? Does It provide more features? I'm just asking, don't get me wrong..

Comment: localStorage will be used along with the window object like `window.localStorage.get(..)` etc, so it is not advisable to go with a window object in your typescript as you have more sophisticated strictly typing. So its advisable to go with a @Injectable service which can be used across

Comment: @developer033, the way localStorage stores the data is it stores the key/value pair. Both key and value must of type string. The object can be converted to a string while storing with something like JSON.stringify and later be converted back to the object while extracting by doing something like JSON.parse. But in most cases, you will get an error saying something like "converting circular structure to JSON". So in that scenario I think using this custom localStorage lib could be useful. I haven't tried this lib myself, so can't really comment on the reliability.

Answer (score 1):

using `localStorage` you can do this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
class Bar {
   baz: number = 11;
}
class Foo {
   bar: Bar = new Bar()
}
@Component({
  selector: 'a-component',
  template: `<br><button (click)='reset()'>Reset</button>`
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit{ 
  foo: Foo = new Foo();
  constructor(){
       this.incrementBaz()
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.foo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo'))
    console.log('baz=', this.foo.bar.baz)
  }
  incrementBaz() {
    let old = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo'))
    if (old) {
        old.bar.baz += 1;
        localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(old))    
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(this.foo))
    }
  }
  reset() {
    this.foo = new Foo();
    localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(this.foo))
    console.log('baz=', this.foo.bar.baz)
  }
}
```

with `localStorage` you can store whatever complex object you want.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it helps. But this does not actually deserialize the `localStorage` contents into the variable `foo` of AComponent, instead you operate on "bare" javascript objects and manually update the `foo` variable. If the `Foo` and `Bar` classes were more complicated (and I would need to preserve them across page refresh), I would need much more extra code to track all variables. Am I correct?

Comment: @user1713059 can you think of an example when you say: If the  `Foo` and `Bar` classes were more complicated, and what processing you want to do on them?

Answer (score 1):

**Your Problem**

I am not understanding exactly what you are trying to do with the counter. So I went ahead and made you a real simple example of a way to manipulate your counter and save it to the `localStorage`.

In my example I show you how to save the data as `JSON` and how to handle it when you retrieve it.

**My Solutions**

I made a punker for you to play with till you get it done. You have to look at the Application tab in the dev tools when you inspect element. Then go to Storage. Then click on the run.plnkr.co storage link to see the counter saved to the localhost.

**Link to Live Code**

[Please see the plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/JSFaIyThEE0LOGOYEhKs?p=preview)

Make sure to look at the file `/src/app.ts`

**Eyes on Example**

[image]

**Code Example**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  foo: Foo = new Foo();
  ngOnInit() {
    // This will always be 12, it would be nice if it would increase with each page refresh.

    var counter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
    var tick = this.foo.bar.baz + counter + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', JSON.stringify(tick));
    console.log('this is my tick ' + tick);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}


class Bar {
  baz: number = 11;
}

class Foo {
  bar: Bar = new Bar()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. I did not make myself clear in the question, I will try again.