# Angular 2 localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, local-storage

I'm trying to work with `localstorage` in angular 2. I'm using `angular cli`.

`app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    currentItem: string;
    newTodo: string;
    todos: any;

    constructor(){
        this.currentItem = (localStorage.getItem('currentItem')!==null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentItem')) : [  ];
        localStorage.setItem('currentItem', JSON.stringify(this.currentItem));
        this.newTodo = '';
        this.todos = [];
    }

    addTodo() {
        this.todos.push({
            newTodo: this.newTodo,
            done: false
        });
        this.newTodo = '';
        localStorage.setItem('currentItem', JSON.stringify(this.todos));

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
 <div>
    <form (submit)="addTodo()">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="newTodo" class="textfield" name="newTodo">
        <button  type="submit">Add Todo</button>
    </form>
</div>

<ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i=index ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="todo.done" />
        <span [ngClass]="{'checked': todo.done}">{{ todo.newTodo }}</span>
        <span (click)="deleteTodo(i)" class="delete-icon">x</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<div>
    <button (click)="deleteSelectedTodos()">Delete Selected</button>
</div>
```

It's a simple ToDo list, but it doesn't persist the data when I reload page.

In chrome inspect > Application > Local Storage I see the data. when I reload page, the data still appears, but it doesn't appears on view and when I add a new todo item, the Local Storage delete old items and update with a new todo.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603319/how-to-store-an-object-of-a-class-type-in-browsers-storage-and-retrieve-it/42603514#42603514) as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified a little the code provided for Pardeep Jain, and woked!

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    currentItem: string;
    newTodo: string;
    todos: any;

    constructor(){
        this.currentItem = (localStorage.getItem('currentItem')!==null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentItem')) : [  ];
        this.todos = this.currentItem;
    }

    addTodo() {
        this.todos.push({
            newTodo: this.newTodo,
            done: false
        });
        this.newTodo = '';
        localStorage.setItem('currentItem', JSON.stringify(this.todos));
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use your code like this

```
constructor(){
    this.currentItem = (localStorage.getItem('currentItem')!==null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentItem')) : [  ];
    this.todos = this.currentItem;
}

addTodo() {
    let local_items = localStorage.getItem('currentItem')
    local_items.push({
        newTodo: this.newTodo,
        done: false
    });
    localStorage.setItem('currentItem', JSON.stringify(local_items));
    this.newTodo = '';
}
```

Reason:

- at the time of adding you set array in localStorage which has only latest object not old objects.
- on refreshing page you are not assigning localStorage objects to todo variable

Comment: I got an error: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'`

Comment: I got it fixed! thank your for your answer it helped me a lot.