# Angular 2 interface and LocalStorage Service

Tags: javascript, html, angular, local-storage

I'm trying to use `localstorage` as a service to save some datas, so I created an interface and a component to call both (LocalStorage Service and interface).

Interface:

```
export interface Items {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    message: string;
    done: boolean;
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

    saved: string = localStorage.getItem('currentItem');
    currentItem: string = (localStorage.getItem('currentItem') !== null) ? JSON.parse(this.saved) : [  ];
    todos: any = this.currentItem;

    save(id, title, message, done) {
        this.todos.push({
            id: id,
            title: title,
            message: message,
            done: false
        });

        localStorage.setItem('currentItem', JSON.stringify(this.todos));
    }

}
```

Component:

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {

    todoForm: FormGroup;

    currentItem: string;
    todos: any;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder,
                private router: Router,
                private storageService: LocalStorageService,
                private items: Items) {
        this.currentItem = (localStorage.getItem('currentItem') !== null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentItem')) : [  ];
        this.todos = this.currentItem;

        this.todoForm = fb.group({
            id: '',
            title: '',
            message: '',
            done: ''
        });
    }

    addTodo(event) {
        console.log(this.todoForm.value);
        this.storageService.save(this.items.id, this.items.title, this.items.message, this.items.done)
        this.router.navigate(['./list']);
    }

   ngOnInit() {}

}
```

`HTML`:

```
<div class="container">
    <form (submit)="addTodo($event)">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Id:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="id" class="textfield form-control" name="id" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titulo:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="title" class="textfield form-control" name="title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Mensagem:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="message" class="textfield form-control" name="message">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have a lot of erros when I try to access the `html` file.

I'm doing a proof of concepts to testing Angular 2 and I would like to use `localStorage` as a service and an interface. I know that I don't need `localStorage` as a service to do it works, but in a big project I think I'll need to use it as a service.

The project I'll develop must be works offline, so instead to call `localStorage`in all components I'm create this localStorage Service.

Does anyone know how I fix this problems?

Using interface and LocalStorage as a service is the best way to develop a big project?

Comment: Errors when trying at access html file? Compile time errors?

Comment: Yes, when I try to acess html file I have an erros. `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error`  and  `Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for t! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:`

Comment: Did you add LocalStorageService to the array of providers in the component decorator?

Comment: Use this as a [**reference**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603319/how-to-store-an-object-of-a-class-type-in-browsers-storage-and-retrieve-it/42603514#42603514)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few errors in your code. I can start first off that skip localStorage altogether. You can just use the service as is, without needing to mix in the local storage there. In a real life app you would make http calls to retrieve data, like something like this:

```
addTodo(todo) {
  //make api request, handle response, return result to component
}

getTodos() {
  //make api request, handle response, return result to component
}
```

You can do exactly the same with your app, but have a local array, e.g `todos`, so your service could look like this:

```
@Injectable() 
export class LocalStorageService {

  todos: Item[];

  constructor() {
    // lets add one item by default
    this.todos = [{id:1,title:'title1',message:'message1',done:false}]
  }

  getTodos() {
    return this.todos;
  }

  addTodo(todo) {
    this.todos.push(todo)
  }
}
```

These todos are available for you during your offline session! :)

---

Then off to your **Component**, errors you have:

1. Do not inject `items` to your constructor, constructor are for providers only
2. You are mixing template-driven forms with reactive forms
3. In your `addTodo` function you are referring to e.g `this.items.id`, but nowhere in your component there is an `item`

Okay, let's look at your form, here I changed your form to template driven, so remove `FormGroup` altogether. You also do not need two way binding. You can construct your form so that the object you get from your form is in the correct format, so that can be pushed to the todos as is. This you achieve in your form by using `name` attribute together with `ngModel`, which binds your form. The `name` attribute will become the key in the object, and of course the value you enter in your form, will become the corresponding value to your key. So your form would look like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addTodo(myForm.value)">
  <label>Id:</label>
  <input name="id" ngModel />
  <label>Titulo:</label>
  <input name="title" ngModel />
  <label>Mensagem:</label>
  <input name="message" ngModel />
  <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

This produces (`myForm.value`) an object like:

```
{
  "id": "",
  "title": "",
  "message": ""
}
```

...when it's empty. Here you also have one more property `done` in your object, so upon submit, before pushing this new todo in your array, let's add that property key:

```
addTodo(value) {
  // push the missing value to object
  value.done = false;
  // call method in service to save the new todo
  this.storageService.save(value)
  // update the list of todos
  this.todos = this.storageService.getTodos();
}
```

Please do read about Angular from the official docs, they have quite good tutorials. Based on the code you have here, please look at **[Services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)**, which uses local mockdata, just as you want to do. Also look at **[Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)**, difference between template-driven and model-driven forms!

Just as a bonus, here is a **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/e24BVySDuqL7szdbL7Lt?p=preview)** to play with :)

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot! I already was looked angular quickstart, but I was trying to do it differently and I don't knew how to work with localstorage and services.

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, I think using services as I have above is absolutely the best way to go, as it mimics the way you would do "in real life". When you move on to use real data, you can use the same methods, and just change to http instead of local data, so it's a good perquisite to when you move over to http :) Glad I could help, I remember how confused I was about Angular 2 when I started, it takes a while to get the hang of it (at least for me), but when you do it's great! :) Have great day and happy coding! :)