# How do I restore an object's prototype after retrieving from local storage using typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a typescript class with a getTotal() method on the prototype.

```
class Score {
    roundOne: any;
    roundTwo: any;
    roundThree: any;
    roundFour: any;
    roundFive: any;
    roundSix: any;
    roundSeven: any;
    getTotal() {
      let total = 0;
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(this.roundOne))) total+=parseInt(this.roundOne);
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(this.roundTwo))) total+=parseInt(this.roundTwo);
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(this.roundThree))) total+=parseInt(this.roundThree);
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(this.roundFour))) total+=parseInt(this.roundFour);
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(this.roundFive))) total+=parseInt(this.roundFive);
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(this.roundSix))) total+=parseInt(this.roundSix);
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(this.roundSeven))) total+=parseInt(this.roundSeven);

      return total;
    }
}
```

The method works for my needs until I save an instance of 'Score' to localStorage and try to retrieve it. The prototype is stripped from the object so I no longer have access to the getTotal() method. Aside from restructuring my code, is there any way to reattach or point the objects to their prototype when I retrieve them from localStorage? Something along the lines of:

```
let scores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scores'));

scores.forEach(function(score){
  // reattach or point to prototype here
})
```

Comment: not sure if it's an exact duplicate but this question may help you solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing a json doesn't result in instance of classes but with simple js objects which contain the same properties.

You have (at least) two ways to solve this:
(1) Add a constructor which can handle this state object:

```
class Score {
    roundOne: any;
    roundTwo: any;
    ...

    constructor(state: Score) {
        this.roundOne = state.roundOne;
        this.roundTwo = state.roundTwo;
        ...
    }

    getTotal() {
        ...
    }
}

let scores = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scores')) as Score[])
    .map(score => new Score(score));
```

Notice that even though I use the type `Score` for the state objects it's not really the case, they just [share the same structure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) (minus the method).  You can make an interface for that as well:

```
interface State {
    roundOne: any;
    roundTwo: any;
    ...
}
```

(2) Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
let scores = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scores')) as Score[])
    .map(score => Object.assign(new Score(), score));
```