# Javascript JSON custom deserialisation

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I'm using a C# app where data classes I use look like this :

```
class Node {
  public string name;
  public int id;
  public Node parent;
  public Node[] children;
  public Data data;
}

class Community {
  public Node[] nodes;
}

class Data {
  public string info;
  public int value;
}
```

I declare in javascript these objects :

```
var Node = {
  name: '',
  id: '',,
  parent: '',
  children: '',
  data: ''
}

var Community = {
  nodes: ''
}

var Data = {
  info: '',
  value: ''
}
```

Those are obviously simplified versions of the real deal, but I'd like to know how I can tell the javascript JSON deserializer to build the fields properly, using the objects I declared.

I need to make some sort of CMS for this so it's important that all the keys are available, even if they hold no value, which is why I want to declare objects and have the deserialiser use them.

For instance, I want to be able to access `Community.nodes[3].data.info` even if it wasn't set in the JSON file.

Comment: Your properties in c# are all private. Is that intentional?

Comment: no, I just made up classes that would illustrate my question... they're all public in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people (including Microsoft ASP.NET) use the [NuGet package Json.NET.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

The [`JsonSerializer`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) class offers a large degree of customisation over how objects are serialized.

However to access a deeply nested field like `Community.people[3].job.salary` you must make sure that there are no null nested objects before you access the last field.

In your example you would probably want to set `Person.Job` to be a default value or pass the `Job` in the constructor for Person.

If the issue is on the JavaScript side I suggest you take a look at the [prototype pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-prototype-pattern/) as a starting point and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript) for reference to assigning to it from a JSON string.

Comment: To clarify, the C# part of this works perfectly, both serializing and deserializing. I'd like to create a web page that takes that JSON and allows me or a client to edit it, and notably add a 'Person' for example.

So I'd like to be able to just instantiate a 'Person' object and manipulate it as an object before reserializing and saving the JSON file.