# Difference between Javascript object and Typescript object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out if a `Typescript` object is same as a `Javascript` object. I have a `typescript` variable into which I want to typecast result of `JSON.parse` which I suppose creates a `javascript` `object` from a `json` but I am unable to do it.

I have the following two classes

```
export class User {
  constructor (public firstname:string,
               public lastname:string,
               public email:string,
               public password:string=""){} 
}

export class UserProfileAPI {
  'external-profile': User;
  constructor(externalProfile:User){ 
    this['external-profile'] = externalProfile;
  }
}
```

I have created a spec to test that an `object` created explicitly is same or similar to object created by `json.parse` but they don't seem to be.

```
 fit('should test if Typescript object is same as Javascript object',()=>{
    let user = new User('manu','chadha','test@test.com');
    let dummyUserProfile:UserProfileAPI= new UserProfileAPI(user);
    console.log('dummy profile is ',dummyUserProfile);
    let dummyProfile2:UserProfileAPI = JSON.parse('{"external-profile":{"firstname":"manu","lastname":"chadha","email":"test@test.com"}}');
    console.log('dummy profile 2 is ',dummyProfile2);
    console.log('dummy profile1 == dummy profile 2',(dummyUserProfile == dummyProfile2));
    console.log('dummy profile1 === dummy profile 2',(dummyUserProfile == dummyProfile2));
    expect(dummyUserProfile).toEqual(dummyProfile2);
    expect(dummyUserProfile).toBe(dummyProfile2);
  });
```

In the above case, `dummyUserProfile` is printed as `LOG: 'dummy profile is ', UserProfileAPI{external-profile: User{firstname: 'manu', lastname: 'chadha', email: 'test@test.com', password: ''}}` but `dummyProfile2` is printed as `LOG: 'dummy profile 2 is ', Object{external-profile: Object{firstname: 'manu', lastname: 'chadha', email: 'test@test.com'}}` and both the comparisons return `false`. Why?

Comment: There may be more to this question, but likely the most important takeaway: Comparing two objects will [**never return `true`**](https://jsfiddle.net/ts02dgr1/) unless you compare an object to itself.

Comment: Then how should I test that the object returned from json.parse is of a certain type?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are not comparing *types* anywhere in your code, but rather just comparing the two objects themselves. I'm not all that well-versed in TS so I'll let someone else chime in with more detail.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JS vs TS.  `{} === {}` will always give you false, for the same reason you're getting false.  Object equality uses reference equality, not value equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as several others have already said in comments: in JS objects never `==` or `===` unless they are the same *reference*. Equality by value doesn't work, ie `{} == {}` is always false. But given an object like `const obj = {}` then `obj == obj` is true. This has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Now to this part of your question:

> I am trying to figure out if a `Typescript` object is same as a `Javascript` object. I have a `typescript` variable into which I want to typecast result of `JSON.parse` which I suppose creates a `javascript object` from a `json` but I am unable to do it.

Two important things here you should understand:

- What you are calling a "TypeScript object" and a "JavaScript object" is really a JavaScript object constructor (or instance of) and a plain JavaScript object. Again this has nothing specifically to do with TypeScript. In ES6 you can define [`class` object types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) and even in ES5 you can with an old-school [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).
- What you call a "typecast" in TypeScript is really just a type assignment (or you may have tried a [type "assertion"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)), meaning it *does not change the object in any way*, it just informs the compiler what you *assume* the type of the object should be. You can assign `any` to any type, but it doesn't mean it's true. There's actually a lot of ways you can break your code by writing wrong type assignments and assertions.

So your real issue is that `JSON.parse()` gives you a plain JS object and you want to turn it into a JS object type instance. There's no built-in way to do this in JS unfortunately but of course you can manually do it after decoding the JSON. See: [Parse JSON String into a Particular Object Prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript)

A simple example in your case might look like this:

```
function decodeUserFromJSON(userJSON: string): User {
   const userObj = JSON.parse(userJSON);
   const { firstname, lastname, email, password } = userObj;
   const user = new User(firstname, lastname, email, password);
   return user;
}
```

Depending on how your test framework compares object instances you should be able to check for equality something like this:

```
const user = new User("a", "b", "foo@bar.com", "1");
const decodedUser = decodeUserFromJSON(`{"firstname": "a", "lastname": "b", "email": "foo@bar.com", "password": "1" }`);
expect(decodedUser).toEqual(user);
```