# Cannot access object property values in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting some JSON object stored from HTML5 local storage and assign it to an object.

```
this.currentWebUser = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")));
```

`currentWebUser` is an object of class my class `WebUser`

```
export class WebUser {
  private _id: number;
  private _connectionID: number;

  public set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  public get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  public set connectionID(value: number) {
    this._connectionID = value;
  }

  public get connectionID(): number {
    return this._connectionID;
  }
}
```

When I try to get the value of `id` by using `this.currentWebUser.id` (In typescript this refer getter method of id) I'm getting undefined value, not the actual value.

[image]

But in chrome console, I can see the actual value is there.

[image]

Need help, Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Its supposed to show like that. You are getting undefined in your editor because you haven't defined and initialized the object. But as soon as you run it in browser, it fetches the data from local storage and the structure becomes known.

Comment: _connectionID is not connectionID

Comment: @noririco _connectionID is private attribute of the class. As mentioned in the question, this.currentWebUser.connectionID means acess the _connectionID value via get connectionID method

Comment: assign value to currentWebUser in constructor itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the value returned by

```
Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")));
```

is not an instance of your `WebUser` class.
It is an Object with the fields that were present in the Json (which is clearly visible in your debugger screenshot).

You can check `currentWebUser.__proto__.constructor` to see that it points to `Object()`, not `WebUser()`

You are able to assign the result of `Object.assign` to `currentWebUser` variable because return type of `Object.assign` is `any`.

You need to make sure that you deserialise to the instance of your class.
There are a few ways to do it, see the following links

- [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)
- [Parse JSON String into a Particular Object Prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript)

```
let webUser = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse('{"_connectionID": 1, "_id":2}'));
let webUser2 = Object.assign(
  new WebUser(),
  JSON.parse('{"_connectionID": 1, "_id":2}')
);
console.log(webUser);
console.log(webUser2);
```

Output:

```
{_connectionID: 1, _id: 2}          // Your code
WebUser {_connectionID: 1, _id: 2}  // What you expect
```