# Is there any way in which we can convert plain object to class object?

Tags: javascript, json, class, object, stringify

I have a `Wallet` class, and `wallet` is an instance of this class.
I had to `JSON.stringify(wallet)` it save in a file. Now, when I do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(wallet))` then it is no more an instanceof `Wallet`.

How to convert this plain object from `JSON.parse` to `intanceof` `Wallet` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON String into a Particular Object Prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873624/parse-json-string-into-a-particular-object-prototype-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Object.assign(target, source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign the properties of the plain object to your instance.

Please do care to read all the gotcha's mentioned in the MDN docs linked, especially if you have nested objects.

```js
let plain = { 
   foo : 'bar',
   count : 42
}
class Complex {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = 'hello';
        this.count = 10; 
    }
    
    getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
    
    getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
let test = new Complex();
console.log(test.getFoo());
console.log(test.getCount());
console.log('==== assigning plain object ===');

Object.assign(test, plain);

console.log(test.getFoo());
console.log(test.getCount());
```

Comment: I am using elliptic curve module, and the object is really very big. So, declaring like this wont be a feasible option.

Comment: Please post an example of your plain object.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Object.assign()`, like so:

```js
const walletLiteral = JSON.parse(response);
const walletInstance = Object.assign(new Wallet(), walletLiteral);
```